# How to find larger numbers of any selected number in a series in an ascending order in NumPy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a series of randomly scrabbled numbers. I want to pick a number (say X), and then find and write larger numbers than X in an ascending order. I’m using Python and NumPy.

EXAMPLE:

```
Series of random numbers:

4, 8, 5, 9, 3, 11, 17, 19, 9, 15, 16


X=4, Then:

4, 8, 9, 11, 17, 19


X=8, Then:

8, 9, 11, 17, 19


X=3, Then:

3, 11, 17, 19
```

Please note that when we pick X, our desire is to put X at the beginning of the ascending series, meaning that the count should start from X.

Also note that we don’t want to sort the numbers in terms of their position. No position change in the numbers. Only reading and writing the numbers in an ascending order. Next numbers in the sequence that are smaller than X should be ignored. Thank you.

EDIT:

```
def get_elements(get_from,get_by):
    return [ (get_from[i], i ) for i in range(len(get_from)) if get_by[i] == 0 ]



def ordered_position():
    ordered_lst = [0] *len(data_arr)
    new_val = 1
    while True:
        print(new_val)
        ge = get_elements(data_arr,ordered_lst)
        if new_val >= len(data_arr) or not ge: break
        first_val, idx_fist_val = ge.pop(0)
        ordered_lst[idx_fist_val] = (first_val,new_val)
        for item, idx in ge:
            if data_arr[idx] >= first_val:
                ordered_lst[idx] = (first_val,new_val)
                first_val = item
        new_val += 1

    return ordered_lst
```

Comment: You need to include some examples of your own attempts at solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.maximum.accumulate` like so::

```
a = np.array([4, 8, 5, 9, 3, 11, 17, 19, 9, 15, 16])
X = 4
withreps = np.maximum.accumulate(a[np.argmax(a==X):])
result = withreps[np.where(np.diff(withreps, prepend=withreps[0]-1))]
result
# array([ 4,  8,  9, 11, 17, 19])
```

Comment: Thank you so much Paul Pranzer for helping me in such a short time. The code worked very well. That's quite perfect. Thank you :)

Comment: Hi @Paul Panzer. I also want to know how I can remove the numbers resulted by the code from the original list.
EXAMPLE:
Series of random numbers:
4, 8, 5, 9, 3, 11, 17, 19, 9, 15, 16
X=4, Then:
4, 8, 9, 11, 17, 19 (We call this ROUND 1)
The numbers resulted in ROUND 1 are removed and the operation goes for the new list as follows:
5, 3, 9, 15, 16
So if we apply the code to the new list, it will generate new results:
X=5, Then:
5, 9, 15, 16

Comment: I also have another problem. The code you sent is perfectly working, but it works for short series of numbers. I can’t run it for longer series of numbers (say having thousands of numbers). Where is the limitation in this code? Thank you.

Comment: @Farzad thousands even millions should be no problem at all. As for your other questions, don't ask them in he comments, just make a new question.