# How to remove numbers in a NumPy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to know how I can remove the numbers resulted by the code from the original list, based on [How to find larger numbers of any selected number in a series in an ascending order in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56146548/how-to-find-larger-numbers-of-any-selected-number-in-a-series-in-an-ascending-or)

EXAMPLE:
Series of random numbers:
4, 8, 5, 9, 3, 11, 17, 19, 9, 15, 16

X=4, Then:

4, 8, 9, 11, 17, 19 (We call this ROUND 1)

The numbers resulted in ROUND 1 are removed and the operation goes for the new list as follows:

5, 3, 9, 15, 16

So if we apply the code to the new list, it will generate new results:

X=5, Then:
5, 9, 15, 16

Edit:

```
a = np.array([4, 8, 5, 9, 3, 11, 17, 19, 9, 15, 16])
X = 4
withreps = np.maximum.accumulate(a[np.argmax(a==X):])
result = withreps[np.where(np.diff(withreps, prepend=withreps[0]-1))]
result
# array([ 4,  8,  9, 11, 17, 19])
```

Comment: Please share what you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following code

```
import numpy as np

rand_nums = np.array([4, 8, 5, 9, 3, 11, 17, 19, 9, 15, 16])
round_one = np.array([4, 8, 9, 11, 17, 19])
res = np.setdiff1d(rand_nums, round_one)
print(res)

# output 
>>> array([ 3,  5, 15, 16])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @hodisr, it's working. Just a problem here that in my work flow, this is important that we could keep the order of numbers and the second duplicates (in this array second 9) after removing the numbers. In this example it should write like this: array([5, 3, 9, 15, 16])

Comment: Afuan habibi, if location matters (for the rounds?) I'd recommend saving in a hashmap (dict in python) with the round and the numbers. good luck!